# Style the content (body) element to cover entire space between a header and a footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

For a 3-element (header, body, footer) column on a screen (100vh), I want the header to be fixed on top and footer at bottom, then body taking up all space in between (in-between space). Note that the header and footer can be any sizes as well (texts or images) so I can't fix their heights in advance.

The body size is unknown in advance, for example it can be the area showing emails. If the body size is less than the in-between space (just a few emails), it will take it all. If it is larger (many emails), it should take it all but **not expand** the page to push the footer all the way down to only be seen when scrolled to bottom. That is, I want each element to be an independent section fixed at top/middle/bottom, having the middle taking all in-between space regardless it is larger or smaller.

I have played around using [Flexbox](http://codepen.io/deanstreet/pen/YzQvzPY) and [Absolute positioning](http://codepen.io/deanstreet/pen/bGRKbea) on Codepen.

There are some *commented out* items in the body to expand and contract the body.

For the flexbox body to take all space, I have `flex: 1 1 auto` but when the body is larger than in-between space, `flex-grow: 1` and `flex-basis: auto` expands the body and pushes the footer down. I can't figure out how to get the body to expand to take up the in-between space but fixed at that height regardless of size.

The absolute-position version works here. Giving the body a height of whatever after header and footer and putting it right below the header. Making header and footer `position: fixed; z-index: 2` fixes them at the top and bottom regardless of the body size. The problem here is that I am assigning some fixed heights to the header and footer but I want them to be un-fixed (auto). I want the layout header to be able to display texts (so maybe 30px high) or images (maybe 100px high).

Please advise. The only and only *solution* I can think of is to use JS to read the header and footer heights in the absolute-positioning version. But I would like to use pure CSS if possible.

Comment: I don't know how to put codepen links here, so just hard-coded them. It says they must be accompanied by code and indented, not sure what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using only css:

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.col-12 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: lightblue;
}

.body {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.footer {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<main class="container-fluid p-0">
  <main class="row h-100">

    <section class="col-12">

      <div class="header bg-info w-100">
        <h1>Welcome to FMail (flexbox)</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="body bg-dark text-white p-0 w-100">
        <h5>The main email box (should always occupy all space between header and footer)</h5>
        <ul>
          <li>Email 1</li>
          <li>Email 2</li>
          <li>Email 3</li>
          <li>Email 4</li>
          <li>Email 5</li>
          <li>Email 6</li>
          <li>Email 7</li>
          <li>Email 8</li>
          <li>Email 9</li>
          <li>Email 10</li>

          <li>Email ...</li>
          <li>Email ...</li>
          <li>Email ...</li>
          <li>Email ...</li>
          <li>Email ...</li>
          <li>Email ...</li>
          <li>Email ...</li>
          <li>Email ...</li>
          <li>Email ...</li>
          <li>Email ...</li>
          <li>Email ...</li>
          <li>Email ...</li>
          <li>Email ...</li>
          <li>Email ...</li>
          <li>Email ...</li>
          <li>Email ...</li>
          <li>Email ...</li>
          <li>Email ...</li>
          <li>Email ...</li>
          <li>Email ...</li>
          <li>Email ...</li>
          <li>Email ...</li>
          <li>Email ...</li>
          <li>Email ...</li>
          <li>Email ...</li>
          <li>Email ...</li>
          <li>Email ...</li>
          <li>Email ...</li>
          <li>Email ...</li>

      </div>

      <div class="footer bg-info w-100">
        <h5>I am the footer (should be fixed at bottom)</h5>
      </div>

    </section>

  </main>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know this `position: sticky` before. Seems like a useful thing.

Comment: Glad it helped :)